# Google tcp load balancer with two/multiple ports

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup a TCP load balancer with both ports (80/443), but google front end dashboard only allows using one port per frontend/ip
I want to be able to enable both ports on the same IP.
I don't want to use HTTP load balancer since it requires the certeficate and I want to generate the certificate on the vm so, i belive HTTP load balancer can't do the job for me.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use multiple frontends with the same IP but the first thing to do is reserve the IP https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible eventually:

1. First, you need to reserve an IP address by going to https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list
2. Create the load balancer and choose that IP when creating the FrontEnd.
3. Once the load balancer is created, it will automatically create a target proxy for you. Find it and get its name, which may probably look like '[lb-name]-target-proxy'
4. Run this command: gcloud compute forwarding-rules create mytargetproxy --ports=443 --address=[IP] --project=[project name] --target-tcp-proxy=TARGET_PROXY_NAME

Note: It may not be possible to create the forwarding rule through the dashboard, so you may need to install gcloud."

In few minutes it w'll work and you may be able to connect to both ports.

Updates 1 Jan 2023:

It's also possible from the dashbaord:
[image]
When you are on the frontend tab:
you click on "add frontend ip and port" and select the early created ip and the port you want to open